# How to call no argument stored procedure inside Trigger

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

I am trying to call stored procedure from trigger

```
create or replace trigger trg_insert
after insert on dbuser_m1 
for each row 
begin
InsertData;
end;
```

but getting below erro

> ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger
>   'OWS_GO_UAT_02.TRG_INSERT'
>   04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
>   *Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
>              this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
>              in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
>   *Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.

Anyone can help me on this please?Thanks,

Comment: is this correct way to call stored procedure inside trigger?

Comment: It has nothing to do with calling a  "no argument procedure" . Problem is that your no argument procedure is trying to access the same table. Show us  the code for `InsertData` or let us know what you are trying to do inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides what @KaushikNayak told, it seems you have a `select` from table `dbuser_m1` while it's being processed by a DML(`insert` in this case).

We don't know your code inside `InsertData`,

but *i guess*,

instead of using such a statement `select col1, col2 into v_col1, v_col2 from dbuser_m1;` ,
you can apply some assignments with some arguments with column values of `dbuser_m1` to your procedure like `InsertData(:old.col1,:old.col2)` while calling, and inside called procedure there maybe assignments :

`v_col1 := :old.col1; v_col2 := :old.col2;`

where `v_col1` is of type `dbuser_m1.col1%type` and `v_col2` is of type `dbuser_m1.col2%type`.